# Access 2016 ODBC to Oracle: getting "cannot insert NULL into" error message even when field is not null

Tags: oracle, ms-access, oracle11g

Because Access can't make anything easy...

I have an Access 2016 front-end connected to an Oracle 11g database. I'm using the Microsoft ODBC for Oracle driver because there is a known issue with the Oracle driver not allowing updates through Access. The MS Oracle driver has been working fine up until now.

When I made my front end, the tables I connected to had the ROW_CREATED_BY and ROW_CREATE_DATE fields set to Nullable. Well, at some point, the DBA decided to set them to Not Nullable.

I have an append query which inserts new records into a table, which was working fine until this change. Now when I run it, I get an "ORA-01400: CANNOT INSERT null into ([table name]."ROW_CREATED_BY"" error message. I updated the query so that the ROW_CREATED_BY and ROW_CHANGE_DATE fields are populated during the insert, but I still get the error message.

I have a test copy of this same database where these two fields are still set to Nullable, and I can insert into it with no issues.

Has anyone else encountered this and knows a work-around? I've found nothing through Google or here at SO, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: **How** do you populate during insert? Did your DBA update rows that already existed before applying this change?

Comment: Yes, it looks like he did update the two fields so they are all populated before setting them to no nulls. I'm not sure what you mean about how I populate during the insert. When I open the table in Access, I add a new record but when I try to save the new record it throws the error and won't save, even though I've populated all of the fields in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally got an answer from the DBA. Turns out the problem was due to a trigger needing to be modified. Once he did that, everything started functioning as it should.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Access is getting blamed for this.  Are you sure you are not overlooking another field that cannot be null?... to sanity test I would append a record that is definitely populating every field from the Oracle perspective...… - - what advice does the Oracle DBA give?...

Comment: You're right--I shouldn't have blamed Access for this one, but most of the time when I've had issues like this, Access was the culprit. In further testing, it appears the problem is on the Oracle side--I'm thinking it has something to do with the drivers. I your recommendation of populating all fields that could not be null but it still gives me the error. I'll be talking to the DBA today.